# Visual Studio Con Sqlite En C#

Tags: c#

Deseo crear una base de datos en Sqlite desde Visual Studio con C# pero quiero saber si al crear el software(.exe) al crear el programa **¿solo crea el ejecutable o un archivo externo como por ejemplo un archivo dll?**, lo que quiero saber es si el resultado final va ser el ejecutable solo o si va a contener otros archivos que dependeran de el.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando creas un programa en .Net el programa es un **.exe** o un **.dll** solamente, a la hora de agregar librerias de terceros o al hacer referencia a otras librerias entonces tendras que instalar el .exe y las .dll de las librerias que necesitas para que tu programa funcione como pudieran ser las librerias para utilizar SQLite.Net.

Hay herramientas como [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630) que te permiten crear un .exe que contenga tu .exe y todas las librerias .dll que necesitas y asi tendrias un único .exe .

Ahora para tu caso en particular, la base de datos de sqlite puede no existir a la hora que instalas la aplicacion pero tarde o temprano tu programa tendrá que crear el archivo de sqlite en algun lugar fuera de tu .exe.

Answer (score 1):

El resultado o producto de tu aplicación depende de cómo se construya la solución. Una solución en Visual Studio puede contener uno o más proyectos y cada proyecto genera un ensamblado compilado que puede ser (principalmente) un archivo EXE o un DLL.

Por ejemplo, si toda la capa de acceso a tu base de datos la generas en un ensamblado o proyecto aparte, dicho proyecto compilará una librería DLL que puede ser enlazada desde tu proyecto principal (que podría ser una interfaz de usuario con ventanas para manipulación de datos) y que utilice los servicios públicos de la misma librería.

Además de lo anterior, normalmente los proyectos integran **referencias** (por ejemplo librerías de acceso a bases de datos, colecciones de controles, clases de utilería o *helpers*, etc.) y que también se incluirán (si así se configura) en la salida final del proyecto.

La decisión de diseño de la solución la hace el programador: el entorno de desarrollo (Visual Studio) te presenta ciertas convenciones a seguir por la plataforma o *framework* .NET, pero la aplicación la construyes como desees. Obviamente puedes hacer uso de [*patrones arquitectónicos*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrones_de_arquitectura) para facilitar la construcción de tu solución, pero eso también es decisión tuya.